# Responsive 3 column Footer Div Issues

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am designing a site on shopify, and the footer looks great on a computer screen, and is responsive, but on the iPad, it looks smashed together. Mobile doesn't really have that issue, so I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Can I just make the entire DIV responsive, or do I need to format each column/section?  I tried to add the same "responsive-image" tag I used for the "do what is right now what is easy" image, but that didnt work.  Any ideas?

www.righteyewearstore.com

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make iPad have 1 column just as in desktop, do this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
.footer-module {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

or even better, in your CSS, replace ALL your 720px media queries for 768px (simply search and replace and that will do the trick)